# own nub function - how to use foldl/foldr?

Tags: list, haskell, fold

Here is my own implementation of nub (remove duplicates):

```
nub :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
nub lista = nub_rec lista []
    where
        nub_rec :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
        nub_rec [] acc = acc
        nub_rec (x:xs) acc = nub_rec (filter (\y -> if y == x then False else True) xs) (x:acc)
```

I consider how to use foldr/foldl to implement nub, could you help me ? I can't see a way.

Comment: By the way, `\y -> if y == x then False else True` is the same as `not . (== x)` or simply `/= x`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First,  your implementation of `nub` is bit more complex than it needs to be (and it reverses the order of elements in the list). Here's a simpler one:

```
myNub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
myNub (x:xs) = x : filter (/= x) (myNub xs)
myNub [] = []
```

Now, if we want to use `foldr` to write a function that will output, not just an "aggregate" but a full list, it's useful to first have a look at the simplest `foldr`-based function that takes in a list and spits out a list:

```
myNoop :: [a] -> [a]
myNoop l = foldr (\ x xs -> x : xs) [] l
```

Given that, the `filter` must be inserted somewhere. Since I assume this is a homework, I'll leave that to the OP as an exercise :)

Comment: Even simpler, `(\x xs -> x : xs)` is equivalent to `(:)`.

Comment: Yes and `foldr (:) []` might as well be `id` ;-) I expanded a bit to make inserting `filter` easier ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, your solution without fold is simpler that my, but my is tail-recusion - your is not tail-recursiob.

Comment: I don't think tail-recursion matters as much in Haskell as in eagerly-evaluated languages. Also your implementation won't work on an infinite list..

Comment: Why my implementation doesn't work on infinite lists? Why does your implementation works ?

Comment: short answer: because you can't reverse an infinite list and your function reverses the list

Comment: @J.Doe Tail recursion and infinite lists don't cope very well. A standard accumulator-based tail recursive solution will start to produce its output only after the whole input list is completely processed. That's never, for infinite input lists.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your clear argument. However, your foldr starts processing with right endpoint. Infinite lists has not right endpoint..

Comment: I wouldn't say that foldr starts from the right. You should look up the implementations of `foldr` and `foldl`.
Notice that
`foldr (:) [] [1,2,3] == [1,2,3]`
whereas
`foldl (flip (:)) [] [1,2,3] == [3,2,1]`

Answer (score 2):

Solution only with filter and foldr without direct (or self) recursion:

```
removeDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
removeDuplicates = foldr (\z ys -> z : filter (/= z) ys) []
```